# How to split a video file along with the corresponding subtitle file?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I have a large video file (`large.mp4`) and a corresponding subtitle file (`large.srt`).

What is the best way to split both the files into *n* equal parts?

This will produce `large-1.mp4`, ... , `large-n.mp4` and `large-1.srt`, ..., `large-n.srt`. And all these files will be of equal size (except the last ones).

What is the best way to split both the files into parts of a specific duration, say, 15 mins?

The output will be similar to the one indicated above.

I would like to use a command line tool, preferably `ffmpeg` and preferably the direct command, without a script.

Comment: Am I understanding you right you want to split the files into a number *n* of (not necessarily corresponding!) files as well as a number of (more or less corresponding) files of *n* minutes duration each? Or do they have to correspond in either way?

Comment: Now that I read your question again after answering I stumbled across *all these files will be of equal size* vs. *split (…) into parts of a specific duration* – those two statements contradict each other and need different approaches. My answer covers the *specific duration* and I think this is what you wanted, if I'm wrong please mention me and let me adjust my answer – `split` comes to mind.

Comment: @dessert Either of the two things would work. Either split into n parts or parts of n sec each. It only means I will need to manually do one calculation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A task as complex like this (to my knowledge) can't be done with `ffmpeg` alone and in one single call, but I'll add a oneline version below. Here's the script version:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
in=$1
dur=$2
totaldur=$(ffprobe -v -8 -show_entries format=duration -of flat large.mp4 | sed -r 's/.*"([0-9]+).*/\1/')
i=0

while (( i * dur < totaldur) )
do
  ffmpeg -i $in -i ${in%%.*}.srt \
    -ss $((i*dur)) -t $dur -c copy -sn ${in%%.*}-$((i+1)).${in#*.} \
    -ss $((i*dur)) -t $dur -an -vn ${in%%.*}-$((i+1)).srt
  ((i++))
done
```

This script takes two arguments, the first one being the video's filename and the second being the duration in seconds, see the example run below. It first pipes the output of `ffprobe` to `sed` to get the video's total duration in seconds, this value is used to build a `while` loop for the parts. Inside the loop `ffmpeg` is called to create the parts, both the `.mp4` and `.srt` in one call.

#### Example run

```bsh
$ tree # the directory contains large.mp4 and large.srt
.
├── large.mp4
└── large.srt
$ ffmpeg -i large.mp4 |& awk '/Duration/' # large.mp4 has a duration of 00:02:30.07
  Duration: 00:02:30.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1283 kb/s
$ /path/to/above/script large.mp4 60 # let's split it after every 60 seconds
$ tree
.
├── large-1.mp4
├── large-1.srt
├── large-2.mp4
├── large-2.srt
├── large-3.mp4
├── large-3.srt
├── large.mp4
└── large.srt
```

#### Oneline version

The first two variables hold the filename and the duration in seconds, adjust those two to your needs.

```
in=large.mp4;dur=60;i=0;while ((i*dur<$(ffprobe -v -8 -show_entries format=duration -of flat large.mp4|sed -r 's/.*"([0-9]+).*/\1/')));do ffmpeg -y -i $in -i ${in%%.*}.srt -ss $((i*dur)) -t $dur -c copy -sn ${in%%.*}-$((i+1)).${in#*.} -ss $((i*dur)) -t $dur -an -vn ${in%%.*}-$((i+1)).srt;((i++));done
```

#### Links

Here are some links I found on the way:

- [FFmpeg: How to split video efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5651654/6164712)
- [Use ffmpeg to add text subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8672809)
- [How to disable subtitles decoding in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12131789)
- [How to extract subtitle from video using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/q/583393)